# Deserialize using DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am trying to Deserialize an xml file that looks  like the following

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Test xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApplication6">
  <values>
    <String>Value 1</String>
    <String>Value 2</String>
  </values>
</Test>
```

to an object that is  this

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApplication6")]
public class Test
{
    [DataMember(Name = "values")]
    public String[] values;
}
```

with

```
var ds = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Test));
        using (Stream stream1 = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Projects\test1.xml"))
        {

            Test rr = (Test)ds.ReadObject(stream1);
        }
```

However none of the values are deserializing. I just see and empty array in Test rr. Could you please tell what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need fine control of the XML that is emitted when serializing, you should not use `DataContractSerializer`. It is has very limited flexibility. You would be better off using `XmlSerializer`, which has liimtitations as well, but is much more flexible than `DataContractSerializer`.

That being said, here is how you can do what you want with `DataContractSerializer`.

Change the default namespace on your xml to use the one that `DataContractSerializer`uses by default.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Test xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
  <values>
    <String>Value 1</String>
    <String>Value 2</String>
  </values>
</Test>
```

Instead of using `string[]` create your own custom type that derives from `List<string>`. This must be done solely for the purpose of having something to hang `CollectionDataContractAttribute` on. `CollectionDataContractAttribute` is what will let you specify the name of the elements inside `<values>`.

```
[DataContract]
public class Test
{
    [DataMember(Name = "values")]
    public TestValues values;

}

[CollectionDataContract(ItemName = "String")]
public class TestValues : List<string> { }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DataContractSerializer` has its own rules for XML and cannot support all XML forms.  I suggest using the [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Use this definition

```
[XmlClass(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApplication6")]
public class Test
{
    [XmlArray("values")]
    [XmlArrayItem("String")]
    public String[] values;
}
```

Comment: Personally I like XmlSerializer over DataContractSerializer. However I cant use XmlSerializer in my project for some other restrictions. Thanks for your response though.